# Flodded logs in 16.04

Tags: 16.04

Following flooding my logs after updrade to 16.04. It is annoying even all seems to work as intended

```
Apr 21 11:36:02 amarone systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 118.
Apr 21 11:36:02 amarone systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 118...
Apr 21 11:36:02 amarone systemd[22508]: Stopped target Default.
Apr 21 11:36:02 amarone systemd[22508]: Stopped Run Click user-level hooks.
Apr 21 11:36:02 amarone systemd[22508]: Stopped target Basic System.
Apr 21 11:36:02 amarone console-kit-daemon[1651]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 21405 was not found when attempting to remove it
Apr 21 11:36:02 amarone console-kit-daemon[1651]: console-kit-daemon[1651]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 21405 was not found when attempting to remove it
Apr 21 11:36:02 amarone systemd[22508]: Stopped target Timers.
Apr 21 11:36:02 amarone systemd[22508]: Stopped target Sockets.
Apr 21 11:36:02 amarone systemd[22508]: Stopped target Paths.
Apr 21 11:36:02 amarone systemd[22508]: Reached target Shutdown.
Apr 21 11:36:02 amarone systemd[22508]: Starting Exit the Session...
Apr 21 11:36:02 amarone systemd[22508]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 22557 (kill).
Apr 21 11:36:02 amarone systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 118.
Apr 21 11:36:02 amarone systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of postgres.

Apr 21 11:44:01 amarone systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of postgres.
Apr 21 11:44:01 amarone systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 118...
Apr 21 11:44:01 amarone systemd[1]: Started Session 3655 of user postgres.
Apr 21 11:44:01 amarone systemd[24157]: Reached target Timers.
Apr 21 11:44:01 amarone systemd[24157]: Reached target Sockets.
Apr 21 11:44:01 amarone systemd[24157]: Reached target Paths.
Apr 21 11:44:01 amarone systemd[24157]: Reached target Basic System.
Apr 21 11:44:01 amarone systemd[24157]: Starting Run Click user-level hooks...
Apr 21 11:44:01 amarone click[24163]: ** (process:24176): WARNING **: Unable to get manifest for 'com.ubuntu.gallery' package: com.ubuntu.gallery does not exist in any database for user postgres
Apr 21 11:44:01 amarone click[24163]: ** (process:24176): CRITICAL **: manifest_version: assertion '*manifest != NULL' failed
Apr 21 11:44:01 amarone click[24163]: ** (process:24176): CRITICAL **: click_triplet_to_app_id: assertion 'version != NULL' failed
Apr 21 11:44:01 amarone click[24163]: (process:24176): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
Apr 21 11:44:01 amarone click[24163]: (process:24176): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
Apr 21 11:44:01 amarone click[24163]: ** (process:24176): WARNING **: Unable to get manifest for 'com.ubuntu.gallery' package: com.ubuntu.gallery does not exist in any database for user postgres
Apr 21 11:44:01 amarone click[24163]: ** (process:24176): CRITICAL **: manifest_version: assertion '*manifest != NULL' failed
Apr 21 11:44:01 amarone click[24163]: ** (process:24176): CRITICAL **: click_triplet_to_app_id: assertion 'version != NULL' failed
Apr 21 11:44:01 amarone click[24163]: (process:24176): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
Apr 21 11:44:02 amarone click[24163]: ** (process:24181): WARNING **: No installed click packages
Apr 21 11:44:02 amarone click[24163]: ** (process:24181): WARNING **: No applications defined
Apr 21 11:44:02 amarone systemd[24157]: Started Run Click user-level hooks.
Apr 21 11:44:02 amarone systemd[24157]: Reached target Default.
Apr 21 11:44:02 amarone systemd[24157]: Startup finished in 363ms.
Apr 21 11:44:02 amarone systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 118.
Apr 21 11:44:02 amarone console-kit-daemon[1651]: console-kit-daemon[1651]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 21495 was not found when attempting to remove it
Apr 21 11:44:02 amarone console-kit-daemon[1651]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 21495 was not found when attempting to remove it
Apr 21 11:44:02 amarone systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 118...
Apr 21 11:44:02 amarone systemd[24157]: Stopped target Default.
Apr 21 11:44:02 amarone systemd[24157]: Stopped Run Click user-level hooks.
Apr 21 11:44:02 amarone systemd[24157]: Reached target Shutdown.
Apr 21 11:44:02 amarone systemd[24157]: Starting Exit the Session...
Apr 21 11:44:02 amarone systemd[24157]: Stopped target Basic System.
Apr 21 11:44:02 amarone systemd[24157]: Stopped target Timers.
Apr 21 11:44:02 amarone systemd[24157]: Stopped target Sockets.
Apr 21 11:44:02 amarone systemd[24157]: Stopped target Paths.
Apr 21 11:44:02 amarone systemd[24157]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 24207 (kill).
Apr 21 11:44:02 amarone systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 118.
Apr 21 11:44:02 amarone systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of postgres.
```

Update with more logs to answer the questions. Keep flooding my logs

```
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of postgres.
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 118...
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[1]: Started Session 4579 of user postgres.
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[12483]: Reached target Timers.
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[12483]: Reached target Paths.
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[12483]: Reached target Sockets.
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[12483]: Reached target Basic System.
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[12483]: Starting Run Click user-level hooks...
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone click[12489]: ** (process:12502): WARNING **: Unable to get manifest for 'com.ubuntu.gallery' package: com.ubuntu.gallery does not exist in any database for user postgres
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone click[12489]: ** (process:12502): CRITICAL **: manifest_version: assertion '*manifest != NULL' failed
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone click[12489]: ** (process:12502): CRITICAL **: click_triplet_to_app_id: assertion 'version != NULL' failed
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone click[12489]: (process:12502): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone click[12489]: (process:12502): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone click[12489]: ** (process:12502): WARNING **: Unable to get manifest for 'com.ubuntu.gallery' package: com.ubuntu.gallery does not exist in any database for user postgres
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone click[12489]: ** (process:12502): CRITICAL **: manifest_version: assertion '*manifest != NULL' failed
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone click[12489]: ** (process:12502): CRITICAL **: click_triplet_to_app_id: assertion 'version != NULL' failed
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone click[12489]: (process:12502): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone click[12489]: ** (process:12507): WARNING **: No installed click packages
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone click[12489]: ** (process:12507): WARNING **: No applications defined
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[12483]: Started Run Click user-level hooks.
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[12483]: Reached target Default.
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[12483]: Startup finished in 359ms.
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 118.
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 118...
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[12483]: Stopped target Default.
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone console-kit-daemon[1651]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 26922 was not found when attempting to remove it
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone console-kit-daemon[1651]: console-kit-daemon[1651]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 26922 was not found when attempting to remove it
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[12483]: Stopped Run Click user-level hooks.
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[12483]: Reached target Shutdown.
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[12483]: Starting Exit the Session...
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[12483]: Stopped target Basic System.
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[12483]: Stopped target Sockets.
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[12483]: Stopped target Timers.
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[12483]: Stopped target Paths.
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[12483]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 12527 (kill).
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 118.
Apr 21 20:56:01 amarone systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of postgres.
Apr 21 20:57:01 amarone CRON[12683]: (root) CMD (cp /home/piece/Bilder/vpimage.jpg /var/www/newhtml/vpimage_0.jpg #VP Bild)
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone CRON[12700]: (root) CMD (/etc/webmin/status/monitor.pl)
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of postgres.
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 118...
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[1]: Started Session 4581 of user postgres.
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[12751]: Reached target Paths.
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[12751]: Reached target Sockets.
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[12751]: Reached target Timers.
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[12751]: Reached target Basic System.
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[12751]: Starting Run Click user-level hooks...
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone click[12757]: ** (process:12770): WARNING **: Unable to get manifest for 'com.ubuntu.gallery' package: com.ubuntu.gallery does not exist in any database for user postgres
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone click[12757]: ** (process:12770): CRITICAL **: manifest_version: assertion '*manifest != NULL' failed
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone click[12757]: ** (process:12770): CRITICAL **: click_triplet_to_app_id: assertion 'version != NULL' failed
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone click[12757]: (process:12770): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone click[12757]: (process:12770): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone click[12757]: ** (process:12770): WARNING **: Unable to get manifest for 'com.ubuntu.gallery' package: com.ubuntu.gallery does not exist in any database for user postgres
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone click[12757]: ** (process:12770): CRITICAL **: manifest_version: assertion '*manifest != NULL' failed
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone click[12757]: ** (process:12770): CRITICAL **: click_triplet_to_app_id: assertion 'version != NULL' failed
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone click[12757]: (process:12770): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone click[12757]: ** (process:12775): WARNING **: No installed click packages
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone click[12757]: ** (process:12775): WARNING **: No applications defined
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[12751]: Started Run Click user-level hooks.
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[12751]: Reached target Default.
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[12751]: Startup finished in 359ms.
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 118.
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 118...
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[12751]: Stopped target Default.
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[12751]: Stopped Run Click user-level hooks.
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone console-kit-daemon[1651]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 26939 was not found when attempting to remove it
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone console-kit-daemon[1651]: console-kit-daemon[1651]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 26939 was not found when attempting to remove it
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[12751]: Reached target Shutdown.
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[12751]: Stopped target Basic System.
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[12751]: Stopped target Sockets.
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[12751]: Stopped target Timers.
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[12751]: Stopped target Paths.
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[12751]: Starting Exit the Session...
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[12751]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 12801 (kill).
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 118.
Apr 21 20:58:01 amarone systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of postgres.
Apr 21 20:58:55 amarone postfix/smtpd[12816]: warning: hostname static.32.85.188.95.dsl.krasnet.ru does not resolve to address 95.188.85.32: Name or service not known
Apr 21 20:58:55 amarone postfix/smtpd[12816]: connect from unknown[95.188.85.32]
Apr 21 20:58:55 amarone postfix/smtpd[12816]: disconnect from unknown[95.188.85.32] helo=1 auth=0/1 quit=1 commands=2/3
```

Comment: Look at these: https://askubuntu.com/questions/735898/cannot-autolaunch-d-bus-without-x11-display/736732, https://askubuntu.com/questions/645968/error-cannot-autolaunch-d-bus-without-x11-display

Comment: Before all that what transpired before this event?

Comment: Added more logs, logs been flooded since upgrade from 14.04