# Fix error: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY on script to change wallpaper using systemd

Tags: bash, scripts, xorg, systemd, desktop-background

### Background

I have created a script that changes my wallpaper periodically. The script works perfectly fine when I run it from bash, but having to manually run it on every startup is becoming annoying, so I decided I would automate the process using `systemd`.

### Scripts

Following is the script that changes the wallpaper:

```
targetDir="/home/mypc/Pictures/Wallpapers"


function get_next_photo() {
    # Returns a random file form targetdir
    files=( "$targetDir"/* )
    echo "${files[RANDOM % ${#files[@]}]}"
}

function set_background() {
    # Takes an absolute file path as argument. Need * for spaces in path
    bg="$*"
    echo "Setting background to $bg"
    dconf write "/org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-uri" "'file://$bg'"

}


while :
do

    background=$(get_next_photo)
    echo "Next background is $background"
    set_background $background
    sleep 5m
done
```

And this is the `systemd` service I created for it, located in `/etc/systemd/system/background-changer.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Periodically changes the background wallpaper, taking random images from the Pictures/wallpapers folder

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/mypc/background_changer.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

### Problem

The problem is that once I start the job using `systemd` the wallpaper never changes.
After checking with `sudo systemd status background-changer.service`, this is what I got:

```
$ sudo systemctl status background-changer.service 
● background-changer.service - Periodically changes the background wallpaper, taking random images from the Pictures/wallpapers folder
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/background-changer.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-01-09 13:17:32 CET; 7min ago
   Main PID: 14196 (bash)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 18936)
     Memory: 596.0K
        CPU: 16ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/background-changer.service
             ├─14196 /bin/bash /home/mypc/background_changer.sh
             └─17655 sleep 5m

ene 09 13:17:32  systemd[1]: Started Periodically changes the background wallpaper, taking random images from the Pictures/wallpapers folder.
ene 09 13:17:32 bash[14196]: Next background is /home/mypc/Pictures/Wallpapers/jonatan-pie-3l3RwQdHRHg-unsplash.jpg
ene 09 13:17:32 bash[14196]: Setting background to /home/mypc/Pictures/Wallpapers/jonatan-pie-3l3RwQdHRHg-unsplash.jpg
ene 09 13:17:32 bash[14198]: error: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
ene 09 13:22:32 bash[14196]: Next background is /home/mypc/Pictures/Wallpapers/jonatan-pie-3l3RwQdHRHg-unsplash.jpg
ene 09 13:22:32 bash[14196]: Setting background to /home/mypc/Pictures/Wallpapers/jonatan-pie-3l3RwQdHRHg-unsplash.jpg
ene 09 13:22:32 bash[17652]: error: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

The last line specifically caught my attention:

```
error: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

I have searched for some time now how to fix this, but every solution I find is widely different. I went from reinstalling graphic drivers, to password managers with stuff in between, but nothing works:

- https://anto.online/guides/cannot-autolaunch-d-bus-without-x11-display/
- [Cannot autolaunch D-bus without X11 $DISPLAY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/735898/cannot-autolaunch-d-bus-without-x11-display)
- https://github.com/zowe/zowe-cli/issues/1139
- https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/error-cannot-autolaunch-d-bus-without-x11-display/11928
- [error: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645968/error-cannot-autolaunch-d-bus-without-x11-display/748046#748046)

Can someone help me understand why ?

Comment: Did you see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/748046/1222991) and give it a try?

Comment: Yes, I also tried that `xhost +` before executing my `systemctl start ...` but to no avail.

Comment: Cool. Perhaps it would be in everyone's best interest to have the "every solution I find is widely different" made a bit more specific so that there isn't a plethora comments that look essentially like mine but with different links 

Comment: Done! Post updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

This is not possible using systemd. Basically the DISPLAY variable will not be accessible to it; variables go from parent to child processes, not the other way around.

A possible way of making this work would be to use a use a `.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart` (for example) but this falls out of scope of this question.

Source:

- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482812&p=14126080#post14126080